Investigating DNS leaks with systemd-resolved
I'm trying to maintain control over my DNS and I'm seeing some suspicious behavior. In particular, I want to ensure that there are no DNS leaks outside my VPN tunnel.
I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur) on linux kernel 6.5.0-28-generic. UFW version ufw 0.36.2. OpenVPN version OpenVPN 2.6.5. resolvectl --version returns systemd 253 (253.5-1ubuntu6.1) (I will admit to not quite being sure if I should call this resolved, resolvectl, or systemd-resolved)
First, here in the logs (journalctl), we can see that, over my VPN connection, DNS queries are being attempted to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1.
May 07 18:52:02 my-hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=my.vpn.ip.addr DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=39532 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59550 DPT=853 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
... 
May 07 18:52:12 my-hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=my.vpn.ip.addr DST=1.0.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=21511 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47042 DPT=853 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
...

Now, those queries are being blocked by the firewall, which is fine and good - that's what I want. But what I don't understand is why these attempts are even being made in the first place. And do note - DNS is working; hostnames are being resolved. I just don't understand why it's attemping to query these servers.
Here are the relevant firewall rules
Status: active
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10.0.0.w 53/udp            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0       # DNS over VPN
10.0.0.x 53/udp            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0       # DNS over VPN
10.0.0.y 53/udp            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0       # DNS over VPN
10.0.0.z 53/udp            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0       # DNS over VPN

This is my /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

Here are my settings in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
[Resolve]
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes

From there, I have a script forcing some DNS options on my regular network interface
resolvectl dns enp0s3 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
resolvectl domain enp0s3 ~.
resolvectl dnsovertls enp0s3 true
resolvectl dnssec enp0s3 true
systemctl restart systemd-resolved

I have these lines in my .opvn config file. These are DNS servers local within the VPN network. You'll notice they're also explicitly allowed on port 53/udp in my firewall rules.
dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.w
dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.x
dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.y
dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.z
dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .

And then I have another script forcing some DNS options after the VPN connection is established.
resolvectl default-route enp0s3 false
resolvectl dnsovertls tun0 false
systemctl restart systemd-resolved

And here's the output from resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=yes/supported
  resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=yes/supported
Current DNS Server: 1.0.0.1
       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
        DNS Domain: ~.

Link 3 (tun0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=yes/supported
Current DNS Server: 10.0.0.w
       DNS Servers: 10.0.0.w 10.0.0.x 10.0.0.y 10.0.0.z
        DNS Domain: ~.

So, my question is, what am I missing? Why is my system attempting to make DNS queries over tun0 to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 when, as far as I can tell, it should only be using DNS servers internal to the VPN network, and when, as far as I can tell, those queries are being resolved successfully?
